# Webpack function fire twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, webpack

I have a/an html page that uses ajax to load another html page without refreshing the page and it seems to work fine . The issue here is whenever the ajax page is loaded it cause the webpack function in the for fire twice when called

HTML CODE

```
<html lang="en" class="page"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body id="home" style="">
  <div id="homePage" class="home">
  <div class="reg">
        <i class="bx bxs-book-add"></i><span>Jobs</span>
      </div>

  </div>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build.js"></script>
<script>
        $(".reg").click (function() {

          $.ajax({
                url: "jobs.html",
                success: function(data,status,jqXHR) {
                    $("#home").html($(data).filter(".main_body,script"));
                    history.pushState(null, null, "jobs.html");
                    
                }
            });    
        });
</script> 

</body></html>
```

Second HTML PAGE is similar to the above

```
<html lang="en" class="page"><head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body id="home" style="">
 <div id="main_body" class="main_body">
 <div class="reg">
       <i class="bx bxs-book-add"></i><span>Home</span>
     </div>

 </div>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build.js"></script>
<script>
       $(".reg").click (function() {

         $.ajax({
               url: "index.html",
               success: function(data,status,jqXHR) {
                   $("#home").html($(data).filter(".home,script"));
                   history.pushState(null, null, "/");

               }
           });    
       });
</script> 

</body></html>
```

webpack index js file

```
async function getAccount() {
    const accounts = await ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    // do something with new account here
    
    numberLoadeds++;
    console.log("Time Called",numberLoadeds);

    console.log("Changed to",accounts[0]);
   
  }

ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {

    getAccount();

  });
```

the webpack configure file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode : 'development',
   entry: './client/index.js', // Our frontend will be inside the src folder
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'build.js' // The final file will be created in dist/build.js

   },
 
   inject: false,
   devServer : {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    compress: true,
    port:8085
   }
   
}
```

What I am suspecting is that the functions duplicate anytime the ajax function is called to change page but i dont know how to prove or identify the issue. Really need help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was associated with the html file. When the jquery ajax function is called it send both the div element and the script without the script tag. When sent to the browser it cannot interpret the sent script. Jquery then tells the browser to eval the sent script leading to duplication.

The solution is actually moving the script tag  to the header and remove the script filter from the data sent by the ajax request.